# DialogFlow V2 Client Library for Android Studio setup

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

How to integrate android application with DialogFlow? There are so many git but all referring to v1. I need V2 client setup for android

Comment: is this what you want? https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes. Thanks @DarShan

Comment: But that's the SDK for V1...

Comment: You found any answer for this? @sriniservion

Comment: That library works fine for v2 also.

Answer (score 0):

We created this [Android Dialogflow v2 client library](https://github.com/Educards/android-dialogflow), which uses the official [Google Cloud Java lib](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/libraries/java) to communicate with Dialogflow.